# Static class variable--use with constructors

Tags: c++

I have a class with a static variable: null.

```
static Pointer<Value> Null;
```

Pointer is a class which uses reference count memory management.

However, I get an error: no matching function for call to Pointer::Pointer()

On the line:

```
Pointer<Value> Value::Null(new Value());
```

Thanks.

**Excerpt of Pointer class:**

```
template <typename T>
class Pointer
{
 public:
  explicit Pointer(T* inPtr);
```

**Constructor Source**

```
  mPtr = inPtr;
  if (sRefCountMap.find(mPtr) == sRefCountMap.end()) {  
    sRefCountMap[mPtr] = 1;
  } else {
    sRefCountMap[mPtr]++;
  }
```

Comment: Is this definition at global scope in a source file ?

Comment: Can you show us more code?  What's going on in your constructor?

Comment: To which class does the `Null` member belong? — Also I think that there is probably a better way to do what you want, e.g. the smart pointer classes from Boost or Boost.Optional.

Comment: Why would you call a variable ''Null''? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your class is named Value.

```
// Header file
class Value
{
public:
    ...
    static const Pointer<Value> Null;
};

// This should be in the cpp file.
const Pointer<Value> Value::Null(new Value);
```

Comment: Is the assumption incorrect? Can you show your Value class with the actual Null static member?

Comment: Also make sure the class definition for your Pointer template is included in the cpp file and that Value itself is included.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
static Pointer<Value> Null;
```

Is call the Pointer::Pointer() constructor.  It apears that your Pointer class does not have such a constructor, but instead has a constructor that accepts `void*`.  So try changing it to

```
static Pointer<Value> Null(0);
```

Comment: Looking at the code you now posted, the problem is that you declared your constructor as `explicit`.  That means that either you have to remove the `explicit` keyword or use `reinterpret_cast<0>` or create a new explicit protected constructor for `void*` for that case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be like:

```
// In the header file.
class Value
{
public:
    ...
    static const Pointer<Value> Null;
};

// In the cpp file.
const Pointer<Value> Value::Null(reinterpret_cast<Value*>(0));
```